# PHP binary data - no machine dependent

Tags: php, binary

I have a little trouble with binary data representation in PHP.
Iam developing communication between web server (php) and foxtrot plc machine. Iam communicating at bite level but i cant find a right functions in php that fits to all my needs ...

I looking for an easy way to handle and convert binary data to and from usint, sint, uint, int, udint, dint, real, string etc. But i need it independent to web server machine - because important part is plc.

Best looking solution is pack/unpack function but iam missing some formats - eg signed long - little endian byte order. And i need every one byte separated.

PLC is 16 bit so sizes are:
sint - 8bit / int - 16bit / dint - 32bit

```
// I need something like this
$lib->convertToBytes(65000); // result [0 => 11101000, 1 => 11111101]
$lib->convertToInt([0 => 11101000, 1 => 11111101]); // result 65000

// And this
$lib->convertToBytes(-65000); // result array
$lib->convertToBytes(658.2); // result array
$lib->convertToBytes(-320.8); // result array
```

My web server is 64 bit so if i call:

```
decbin(-65000) // i get "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000001000011000" (64)
pack('l', -65000) // i get "\x18\x02\xff\xff" (4) - this seems good but i need machine independent representation - little endian byte order in every situation
```

Do anyone know function/functions/library i can use?

Thanx

Comment: As i wrote, i searching for something machine independent.

Comment: No, i ask for some php functions that are machine independent i missed out. Or some existing library i doesnt find. But as i see it doesnt exists. So i write it by my own. Thanx

Comment: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2454-PHP-Serialize-and-unserialize-binary-data.html#view_files

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [pack()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function.  It doesn't have signed/unsigned variants of all types because they are not necessary, as the documentation notes:

> "Note that the distinction between signed and unsigned values only
> affects the function unpack(), where as function pack() gives the same
> result for signed and unsigned format codes."

To get the individual bytes you can use shifts and masks.  This works by shifting the byte you want down into the low 8 bits, then using an AND operation to mask off the other bits that you don't want (setting them to zero).

Low byte: `$val & 0xff;`

Second byte: `($val >> 8) & 0xff;`

Third byte: `($val >> 16) & 0xff;`

To convert from individual bytes to a whole number, you do the reverse:

`$val = $byte[0] | ($byte[1] << 8) | ($byte[2] << 16) ...`

And so on.